# identity server implicit flow and losing post data

Tags: asp.net, identityserver3, openid-connect

We are currently using Identity Server, implicit flow, as part of our asp.net mvc 5 application to handle authentication and authorization calls to our web api.

There are times when a user comes to a form and fills out the data, by the time the user clicks the submit button the token as expired.  This causes the application to redirect to identity server to refresh their token and the user is eventually brought back to the form their were own, but have to refill everything as the data they posted was lost.  Is there a way to maintain that data so when they come back either it's prefilled or the application submit its when it gets a new token?

Initially when this happened we increased the lifespan of the token to 1hr, which might cause an issue as our company policy is 20 min timeouts, so we'd like to reduce the token to 20 mins, but then there are more chances of this happening.

Comment: Haven't you tried to use refresh tokens and refresh access tokens before they expire ?

Comment: @KcDoD Is there a way to check if they are expired before the data is posted?

Comment: now that you need to do from your logic. You will have to check the issued time of the token and match it with expiration time before sending the request (considering the id token).

Comment: Furthermore, though it's not very clear on internal implementation, redirects on posts are not supported well. Indeed there is http 307, but this might be not happening in your case. A good post is here - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem, if so how did you do it. ?